# How to run build script in CRA when node_modules is in parent directory?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a file structure that looks like this:

```
/client
  |--/src 
  |--package.json
  |--/build
/controllers
/models
app.js
package.json
/node_modules
```

My client folder has all of the CRA stuff in it, however I gutted the package.json file to only include the scripts. Client has none of the dependencies as I moved them into the parent package.json file. The start script works exactly like it should. However when I run the build script I get the following error:

```
'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I've tried removing `node_modules` and reinstalling but that hasn't fixed the problem. This leads me to believe that the `build` script is looking for the react-scripts in the same directory that the client package.json is in. 
I can't just move the build script up to the parent directory though as then it can no longer locate the index.html file. Anyone know of a way to help react-scripts be found in the parent directory before I'm forced to have 2 node_modules?

Answer (score 2):

so I found that using this command in the parent directory let's react-scripts know where to look for node_modules

```
"build": "npm run build --prefix client",
```